# Play audio when app is not in foreground or app is inactive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I do not want any code but want to get reference that how can we play audio in background in multitasking devices when application is running in background not in foreground...

Please help me to solve this question.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved this question by referring [iOS Application Background tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

and make some changes in `.plist` file of our application..

Happy coding...

Answer (score 3):

There is developer documentation available here:

- [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4)
- [Playing Background Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW14)
- [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875)